# Finding matching inner text in HTML controls and changing its format using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating a page which renders a list of linkbuttons and labels. Now I want a javascript that parses the inner text of these controls and makes bold those with keywords that match like Google does while rendering a list of websites with linkbutton and its description.

How should i proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the collection of link buttons and label elements use `getElementsByTagName`, then iterate through the collection and use the `innerHTML` property to access the content within them and match against your keywords. Then for the matching elements set the `style.fontweight` property to bold.

Comment: what specifically do you need help with? Search Google for the keywords; getElementsByTagName, innerHTML and style.fontweight. I would suggest that you really need to understand the DOM of a web page before attempting this.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started: http://www.nsftools.com/misc/SearchAndHighlight.htm