# Changing HTML with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I'm trying to replace every instance of "Administrator" on my page with "Admin" Or something similar to that. How would I replace that? If it helps, the span is inside an  tag that has the class "user-title".
Like [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925342/finding-matching-inner-text-in-html-controls-and-changing-its-format-using-javas) but I kinda need to be fed the answer. This is my first time working with javascript.

```
<ul class="author-ident"> 
    <li class="username">
        <a title="Go to Different55's profile" href="http://fwin.co.cc/pun/profile.php?id=2">Different55</a>
    </li> 
    <li class="usertitle">
        <span>Administrator</span>
    </li> 
    <li class="userstatus">
        <span>Online</span>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Post some sample HTML for better responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work mostly with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) so I can only give you a JQuery solution of the top of my head. Sorry if this is not an option for you. With JQuery you could do this...

```
$(".user-title").each(function(index){
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace("Administrator", "Admin"));
});
```

NOTE: If you expect more than one instance of "Administrator" per span tag then you will need to do a regex replace like follows...

```
.replace(/Administrator/g, "Admin");
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) for more info on the regex flag (e.g. "g" means global - more than one)

**EDIT**: Here is a javascript version....

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("user-title");
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++)
{
  spans[i].innerHTML = spans[i].innerHTML.replace(/Administrator/g, "Admin");
}
```

**ANSWER**: This is based on your provided sample HTML (note that I have changed the class name "usertitle" based on your html, check if this is correct)...

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("usertitle");
for (var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++)
{
    var spans = parents[i].getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(var j = 0; j < spans.length; j++){
        spans[j].innerHTML = spans[j].innerHTML.replace(/Administrator/g, "Admin");
    }
}
```

The JQuery equivalent...

```
$(".usertitle span").each(function(index){
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace("Administrator", "Admin"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
document.getElementById('anId').innerHTML = 'my friend';
 }
</script>
<p>Welcome to the site <b id='anId'>dude</b> </p> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
```

This will change the content of that

.
You can run  JS that will look in every span and, if you find "administrator", that you can be use that snippet of code.

Answer (score 1):

To do the replacement you mentioned (replacing all occurrences of Administrator with Admin inside all spans inside .user-title, use:

```
$('.user-title span').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Administrator/g, 'Admin'));
});
```

NOTE: Assuming you are using jQuery in your app

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function :

```
function correct() {
var a  = document.getElementsByClassName("user-title");
var i = 0;
for(i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
       while((a[i].innerHTML).indexOf("Administrator") >= 0){
    a[i].innerHTML = a[i].innerHTML.replace(/Administrator/g, 'Admin');
       }
}
}
```

this function will get collection of all elements having class name as "user-title". then the n in for loop, we will access each element in collection, see if it's innerHTML has the word that you want to replace and if it has, we replace it.

Comment: updated: add a while loop to recursively check weather all instances of the word "Administrator" have been replaced or not

Comment: Would be better off using the replace function here

Comment: Sorry, I meant without your while loop. It appears to add nothing worth while, your regex with the "g" flag will already replace all instances

Comment: ohhh, yes I realised that. You are right. while loop is a waste. "g" flag is there to replace all the instance. :D

Answer (score 0):

Put all instances of the word "Administrator" into a `<span>` with a certain class, f.i.:

```
<span class="user_type">Administrator</span>
```

Then you can use jQuery to do:

```
$("span.user_type").html("Admin");
```

Note that this may not be the nicest thing to do but we don't have any other details on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What other info would you need?

Comment: How does this help? He may as well just put "Admin" in his spans if you are expect manually setting up like this

Comment: It's just good practice. Substituting the word over the document as many suggest is not good practice.

Comment: You are missing my point. If the OP could just add "Administrator" to each span. He may aswell just put "Admin" there instead and forget all the javascript completely. The point is, for one reason of another, he needs to replace one value with another